# Kafka Join 2 Streams (Kafka 1.0.1)

Tags: java, join, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a simple question. I want to join 2 `KStream`s on the same key with a `GenericRecord` as value:

```java
final KStream<String, GenericRecord> obs = builder.stream("Observations");
final KStream<String, GenericRecord> foI = builder.stream("FeaturesOfInterest");

final KStream<String, GenericRecord> transformfoIT = foIT
    .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(value.get("Observation").toString(), value)); 

final KStream<String, GenericRecord> merged = obsT.join(
    transformfoIT,
    (value, location) -> {
        value.put("FeatureOfInterest", location);
        System.out.println();
        return value;

    });
```

`tranfsfromfoIT` is simply so set the keys right. So that `obs.key` and `tranformfoIT.key` is the same for the messages.

But my join is not working because I get :

> The method join(KTable, ValueJoiner) in the type KStream is not applicable for the arguments 
>    (KStream, ( value,  location) -> {})"

I have no idea how to fix it.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

To join two `KStream` you also need to provide a join-window via `JoinWindows` parameter. Compare:

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-kstream-join

Because the third `JoinWindows` parameter is missing, the compiler think you want to call `join(KTable,...)` instead of `join(KStream,...)` and the types are obviously not compatible.